# Aggregation in Logstash-ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash with input-elasticsearch and output-elasticsearch.Both Elastic Search have a different instance.
Before the data goes to the output block,I want to aggregate some documents,create a hash of the new document and insert the nested document in the elastic search.
So basically I want to do some processing before nested document is inserted in the elasticsearch.Is this possible?

```
input{
    # something here to get a value of variable stored in a different file
    elasticsearch{
    hosts=>"abc.de.fg.hi:jklm"
    query=>'{--some query---}'
    }
    }
    output{

    elasticsearch{
    hosts=>"xxx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy"

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's is currently no way of running aggregations from within Logstash. For what it's worth, there's a plugin I've been working on that does this, but I've not released it yet. I'll update this thread when I get something running. You might want to look into the [`aggregate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) in the meantime, that might do the trick.

Comment: no news how to use aggregation

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the "aggregate" plug in.

In my case the input is From UDP and i filter it with "grok" but i believe you can achieve what you want to do by tweaking the code a bit.

Without a sample of you are trying to achieve exactly, the best this i can do is show you a sample of my code:

```
aggregate {
    task_id => “%{action}_%{progress}”
    code =>
    “
    map[‘avg’] || = 0;
    map[‘avg’] += event.get(‘elapsed’);
    map[‘my_count’] || = 0;
    map[‘my_count’] += 1;

    if (map[‘my_count’] == ${LogstashAggregationCount})#Environment variable
        event.set(‘elapsedAvg’, (map[‘avg’] / map[‘my_count’]))
        event.set(‘Aggregetion’, true)
        map[‘avg’] = 0
        map[‘my_count’] = 0
    end
    “
}    
if (![Aggregetion]) {
    drop {}
}
```

Of curse you need to adapt it to your specific case. For more in depth explanation of my code read here: [How to Use Logstash Aggregations](https://dzone.com/articles/logstash-aggregations)